# WCF Service proxy not generating custom Enum types

Tags: wcf, web-services, enums, datacontractserializer

I am making reference to a service that exposes an `Enum` type in the service namespace.  When the proxy is generated the `Enum` type is not present.  What causes this to occur and how do I resolve?

**Note:** adding this as a *web reference* generates the type, as a *service reference* it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using the `Enum` inside your [`ServiceContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx) - it may not be known. You could try using [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) and marking the `Enum` as `public` with [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and each `Enum` member as [`EnumMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx).

You should also try explicitly assigning values to the `Enum` types like this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum EnumType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Value1= 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Value2 = 1
}
```

instead of...

```
[DataContract]
public enum EnumType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Value1,
    [EnumMember]
    Value2
}
```

Comment: The type is used in the a method contract